# Can I access local Postgres server from local Redash?

Tags: postgresql, redash

I try to access local Postgres server from local Redash server.
However, I can't access the database server.

Redash says, could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?.

I can access to the database from pgAdmin and A5:SQL.

Way can't access to local Postgres server?

I want to access local Postgres server from local Redash.

Comment: how have you installed your local Redash? Is it running on docker?

Comment: Thanks for comment. The Redash is running on docker, so I can solve this problem by setting 'host.docker.internal' to host name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can solve this problem, by setting 'host.docker.internal' to host name, not 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1'.